# Change foreign key data type from bigint to string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

While im trying to save an instance of a model I get the error for having wrong data type in foreign key it says it must be a bigint however the primary key is charfiled of the model which is made as a foreign key.

I checked the primary key again, I tried explicitly to link to the name field of that model

here's my models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=30,primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, to_field='name', db_column='department_name', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=100)


invendb=# \d inventory_purchase
                     Table "public.inventory_purchase"
     Column      |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 invoice_no      | character varying(30)  |           | not null | 
 date            | date                   |           | not null | 
 seller          | character varying(100) |           | not null | 
 department_name | bigint                 |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "inventory_purchase_invoice_no_2b78f964_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (invoice_no)
    "inventory_purchase_department_id_28c8ef42" btree (department_name)
    "inventory_purchase_invoice_no_2b78f964_like" btree (invoice_no varchar_pattern_ops)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

access the db shell using

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

then alter the datatype manually

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name
ALTER COLUMN your_column_name
TYPE VARCHAR(30);
```